# Add volume to mongoDB Percona operator

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, percona, kubernetes-mongodb-sidecar

I'm trying to add Filebeat container to the rs0 StatefulSet to collect the logs of my mongoDB. I added a filebeat sidecar container to the operator ([according to the docs](https://www.percona.com/doc/kubernetes-operator-for-psmongodb/sidecar.html)), and now I'm stuck. How can I create an emptyDir volume that would be mounted and accessible on both the mongod container and the filebeat container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The percona guys helped my find a solution, a bit of a hack but it worked for me

you can't create a new volume for the mongod container but you can map one of the existing volumes to the sidecar container, for example:

```
sidecars:
- image: ...
  command: ...
  args: ...
  name: rs-sidecar-1
  volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /mytmp
      name: mongod-data
```

[link for the original post on percona community forum](https://forums.percona.com/t/mount-volume-to-rs0-statefulset-in-percona-operator-in-kubernetes/16410)